# Socle of a group and the Fitting subgroup of a solvable primitive group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, socle

I have been puzzled by this lately. And first, thank you to whoever takes the times to read through these questions.

Consider a finite group $G$ which is solvable.
Let $F(G)$ define the Fitting subgroup of $G$ and $soc(G)$ the socle of $G$.

- Consider for the following cases that $G$ is a primitive group (There
  is a maximal subgroups $M<G$ such that $Core_G(M) = \{id_G\}$).

  Then, from “Finite Soluble Groups” of Doerk and Hawkes, we have that
  (Theorem 15.6, pp54)

  > Let $G$ be a primitive soluble group with stabilizer $M$. Then $G$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup $N$, the stabilizer $M$
  > complements $N$ in $G$, and $N=C_G(N) = F(G)$.

  (I believe here that *"the stabilizer $M$ complements $N$ in $G$"*
  means that $G = F(G)M$.

  A few pages ahead we read (pp. 56 - Concluding Remarks)

  > If $G$ is a primitive soluble group, we can write $G=NM$, with $N=soc(G)$ and $M$ a stabilizer.

  **First question:** If $G$ is a primitive solvable group, then $soc(G)=F(G)$?

EDIT : Removed the second part of the question

> Now, consider that $G = N\rtimes A$ is a solvable (but not necessarily primitive) group, with $N$ being an abelian normal subgroup of $G$, $N\cap A = \{id_G\}$ and $Core_G(A)=\{id_G\}$. Let $k = |N|$.
>
> Computationally I can see that, for small cases, when $gcd(k,2) = 1$, then $N = F(G)$.
>
> **Second question:** Is this a known fact? If so, is there a reference about it?
>
> **Third question:** Based on this, given a $G$ solvable group, if $gcd(|F(G)|,2)=1$, then there is a $A\leq G$ such that, $F(G)\cap A =\{id_G\}$ and $G = F(G) \rtimes A$? Does this need $A$ to be core-free (or else it would be in the $p$-cores of $F(G)$)?
>
> **Final question:** Is there anywhere where I could find more information on the structure of these kind of solvable groups (with more or less restrictions)?

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, and provide context with each question.

Comment: Question 1: yes. Question 2: no. I agree with Shaun.

Comment: Thank you for your input. And I am sorry for asking too much in one post. I will edit and only maintain the first half (with the first question) and repost the second part as a separate question (with more context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N=F(G)$ be the minimal normal subgroup of $G$ in Theorem 15.6 of Doerk and Hawkes.

If $L$ was another minimal normal subgroup of $G$ then we would have $L \cap N = \{1\}$ and so $[L,N] = 1$ contradicting $C_G(N)=N$. So $N$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup and hence $N = {\rm soc}(G)$.